# Should I render dynamic charts in Django or serve them from another webapp?

Tags: django, plot, charts, web-applications, production

Here is this Django webapp hosted in a Apache2 server with mod_wsgi

My question is:
How do I add dynamic graphs to my webapp?

In producion, in order to serve files, Nginx reverse proxy server catches the urls with the /static/ subdomain and serves the content (otherwise the request is redirected to apache)

Google returns planty of ways to address the matter. Do you have any recomandation or relatable experience that I should know before choosing any?

My concerns are:

- How clients update graph data without refreshing the whole page ? (I currentlly use htmx for rendering html)
- Should I use a second webapp to serve the content to nginx redirect?
- Is django-plotly-dash the most straight way? Will it work with htmx or else?

I tried to periodically render an html with a plotly graph using htmx; resulted awful